# Android app - how to save settings for a day and for several days

Tags: java, android, sql

I can not understand a thing.
I'm creating an app that allows you to book at the restaurant.

The restaurant owner will have to enter information about his restaurant with, for example, the number of seats available.

What I want is that he has the possibility to set, for example, the settings for the month of January, but also that for one or more days of January, he can change the settings.

**Example:**

For the entire month of January, there are 30 places available, but the restaurant owner wants to put 10 places on 10th January.

**How can I do?**

What I can not understand is how to save in the DataBase for more days, for example for a month.
Can you give me some advice on how to save the settings on the database?

Sorry if I have not posted the code, but I have no idea how to do it.

I do not know if it can be done, but I thought that the restaurateur could select the days on the calendar and go to the Database the date of each day selected and save the settings for those dates.
But after that I should automatically delete the dates below the current date.

Please help me understand how to do it.

Comment: Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow's format, but for a hint you may look into using shared preferences, as well as using a SQLite database.

Comment: I thank you for the answer Tim.
Surely I have not expressed well, what I can not understand is how to save multiple dates simultaneously in a database

Comment: This is easy, the harder part for you is going to be setting up your app and database.  Once that's in place, I don't expect you to have many blockers after that.

Comment: because the settings will be inserted in the database through the form, but I can not figure out how to associate more dates with that information.

Comment: Is it a technical or a design problem ?
Technical: -> as @TimBiegeleisen said, check how to store data from your app
Design: -> You could have two tables: one table for the monthly available places, one for the daily. Then by default you use the monthly number, but if the daily number is set, then you can use it :)

Comment: The problem is design

Comment: Is it better to have the tables in the SQLite Database or in the Mysql Database on the server that I use to save the other data?

Comment: Keep it with the rest (unless you have a specific reason not to). @M.Loira